# PPPD connection without interrupt

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem, pppd

I try to get a system working with a modem and the following services :

1. permanent Data connection (2G/3G/4G) using old serial interface (not qmi/wmi)
2. permanent polling in AT command for getting SMS and get monitoring information like signal, provider, cell...

Does this modem can be connected 24/24 without any interruption ? Actually I have fast every day one or two small interruption of data (1 to 10 minutes).

The main question is, does a Modem can be connected to the provider 24/24 without interrupt, or it's a standard behavior to be disconnected sometimes ?

Additional note : I have multiples devices, and the PPPD binary fail in 10 minutes on all devices.

I have collect some logs, and I can see the system is disconnected each ~720 minutes = 12 hours :

```
Sep 14 20:23:02 daemon.info pppd[1905]: Connect time 718.6 minutes.
Sep 15 08:23:02 daemon.info pppd[19903]: Connect time 719.9 minutes.
Sep 15 20:23:03 daemon.info pppd[2493]: Connect time 719.9 minutes.
Sep 16 08:23:03 daemon.info pppd[16865]: Connect time 719.9 minutes.
Sep 16 20:23:03 daemon.info pppd[31234]: Connect time 719.8 minutes.
Sep 17 08:23:03 daemon.info pppd[13827]: Connect time 719.8 minutes.
```

Comment: Can you clarify, please, as there is no need for `pppd` to send `AT` commands for retrieving SMSes unless you need to have a data link up at the same time. Nonetheless, what about monitoring `pppd` and if it crashes, retard it ? `wvdial`does it automatically.

Comment: Sorry, my post was not very clear. I have add some context and clarify the question. I didn't known wvdial but he's not active since 2009, so I am not very confident about the future. And as I need to collect bunch of data from AT command, I think this will create more problem than resolve.

Comment: I have a monitoring system based on a RPi and a cheap 3G USB Stick. The `pppd` daemon crashes once or twice a day. I don't know really the reason as the logs are not really clear. The main problem with USB sticks is that the `tty` of the modem changes upon restart or reinit. `wvdial` manages the devices like `/dev/ttyUSB0` that changes into `/dev/ttyUSB4`, etc automatically so I don't have to worry about the reconnection (For some topics, I'm a believer in the "let it crash and recover cleanly" philosophy...)

Comment: It is possible to keep packet data connection (like GPRS) open via pppd 24/7. And also use AT command during the same time. Do you use 2nd serial link or multiplexer channel for sending AT-commands?

Comment: Yes, I use two differents serial link. Actually I think pppd is disconnect by the provider/network because I have multiples system who are disconnect at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the provider / cells. The system will de-register your modem each X hours (in my case 12 hours).

The best solution I have found is to set the option --persist on pppd. The system take ~1 minutes to re-register, but PPPD stay alive.